# Need to move postgis database to new linux machine...best method?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, redhat

We're running out of room on our hard drive, and we're forced to move our postgis database to a new linux redhat machine.  When our IT person copies the directories over to the new machine, I assume the entire database structure won't copy over perfectly.

We are running Red Hat 6 on the old and new machine.  The postgresql version is 9.4.9 and the postgis version is 2.1.8.

Do you have suggestions for steps to take to successfully move our postgis-enabled PostgreSQL database to the new machine, keeping of course all data, structure, tables, etc.

I have seen some tutorials on this, but nothing really recent online.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

If the architecture is the same on both machines (e.g., both are x86_64), the PostgreSQL version is the same (the third digit can be different) and the RedHat version is the same (so that the same version of `glibc` guarantees that the collations are the same), you can simply copy the data directory (and all tablespaces) to the new machine and you are good.

Otherwise, use `pg_dumpall` to dump the old cluster and restore to the new machine.